# Why is いつも used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, usage, particle-と

Consider this sentence:

> **いつもと**変えてたまに外で食事しよう。

This was translated as:

"Let's occasionally change where we go to eat out."

I have two questions:

1. If いつも means always/usually, I don't understand how that fits into
   the translation because たまに expresses "occasionally".
2. If いつも is an adverb/noun, how is the と particle used in this
   sentence?

An explanation of how the grammar works would be appreciated.

Comment: 訳がデタラメなのに、この原文と訳のペアー、なぜかネット上で出回ってしまってる。

Comment: Yeah, the Tanaka Corpus is known to contain errors and low quality examples, but it's freely available so it ends up everywhere, I guess…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 「いつもと変{か}えてたまに外{そと}で食事{しょくじ}しよう。」

And someone translated that to:

> "Let's occasionally change where we go to eat out."

Now, I have to say that the ***original and the translation do not match at all***.  Frankly, the translator does not seem to be very proficient in Japanese.

The speaker of the original sentence (and his/her group/family) usually eat at home.  (いつも = usually)  On this particular day, however, s/he is suggesting to make a change in that habit and go out to eat instead.  Are you following?

The problem is that that is **not** what the translated English sentence says at all.

> 1. If いつも means always/usually, I don't understand how that fits into the translation because たまに expresses "occasionally".

As I stated, that translation is a complete flop.  It would not be very productive to discuss which word went where.

> 2. If いつも is an adverb/noun, how is the と particle used in this sentence?

Here, 「いつも」 is a noun, so no problem with the 「と」.  This 「と」 indicates the "standard" when talking about making a change.  「いつも」 is the standard and they want a change from that and go eat out.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, when I read that sentence I think it means something more like:

Instead of always [eating here], let's go out to eat once in a while.

or perhaps,

Changing from usual, let's eat elsewhere occasionally.

いつも here is kind of being used as a nominal, yes, but really the nominal you are dealing with is in fact いつ itself, followed by two particles (も and と）. と is being used in its coordinating sense, the same way it is used in これと違います ("it's different from this").

You can think of いつも as what is being changed by 変える. と can link a nominal to a predicate (see chapter 10B-3 of Japanese: The Spoken Language) carrying a sense of "accompaniment." This meaning is so broad that it allows us to construct sentences like　いつもと変える ("different/changing *from* usual") and 課長と相談する ("consult *with* the section leader").